# Deciding to use Authorization or not on a per-request basis in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing an ASP.net core MVC 2.2 app and at the moment I'm using the classic `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes on my controller actions to decide whether a certain action can be accessed anonymously or requires authorization.

However, I have a requirement where certain actions should require authorization only if a certain header is missing from the http request. Usually I would implement this by simply having something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("something"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SomeActionWithAuth");
    }
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult SomeActionWithAuth()
{
    ...
}
```

however, in this particular case I have a strict requirement to avoid redirects, so I cannot use this approach.

So my question is:

- Is there a way to intercept the request before it reaches the controller and decide at runtime, on a per-request basis, if the request should require authentication or not?
- If that is not possible, is there maybe a way to decide at runtime which controller/action to route the request to? (that way I could have a setup similar to the one above, with two actions with different auth requirements, but without causing an actual HTTP Redirect on the client side, which I cannot do)

Comment: You just write your own authorization filter that replaces the `Authorize` / `AllowAnonymous` filter. Writing filters is [rather straightforward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authorization-filters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own authorisation policy to handle this.

```
public class HeaderRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public HeaderRequirement(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }

    public string Header { get; }
}

public class HeaderRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HeaderRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HeaderRequirementHandler (
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        HeaderRequirement requirement)
    {
        var hasHeader = context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(requirement.Header);
        if (hasHeader) // if we have the header
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement); // authorization successful
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register the handler as a service

`services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, HeaderRequirementHandler>();`

Add the policy to the authorisation services

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("SomeHeader", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new HeaderRequirement("SomeHeader")));
    });
```

Now you can use it like this: `[Authorize(Policy = "SomeHeader")]`

If you need it a little bit more dynamic, If you don't want to register every single header that could possible be authenticated but rather interpreted at run-time. You can write you own [policy provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is: will this approach behave like the "standard" authorization filter if I don't call "context.Succeed()"? Because if I don't find the required header I  need it to "fall back" on the standard behavior of the default [Authorize] attribute, which in my case performs NTLM/Windows authentication.

Comment: @Master_T I can't say for sure because it highly depends on how you have configured your authorisation.

Comment: I just tested it... it works! (kinda). If I return without calling context.Succeed() the default Authorize behavior (in my case: NTLM auth) is executed (the browser receives the standard NTLM auth challenge). After authentication has passed, the `HeaderRequirementHandler` gets called a second time. This by itself would cause an infinite loop, but since the second time the user is now authenticated if I don't find the header I'm looking for I directly check the context.User object to see if user is authenticated and perform my permission checking logic directly there. Thanks!